# Select the highlighted row of dynamically created table,onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a web page generating dynamic table depending on the data length. Now i want to fetch the value of selected tr of table and append it into another table.

```
function setItemForSale(itemForSale, type,xml)
{

        var itemForSaleTable = document.getElementById("custorder1");
        var itemForSaleTableHead = document.getElementById("head1");
        var itemForSaleTableBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(itemForSaleTableHead);

        $('#custorder1 tr').has('td').remove();            

        for(var i=0; i< itemForSale.length; i++)
        {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            itemForSaleTable.insertRow(-1);

                var obj             = itemForSale[i];
                var vitemno         = obj["itemNo"];
                var vname           = obj["name"];
                var valias          = obj["alias"];
                var vbrand          = obj["brand"];
                var vdescription    = obj["description"];

                var cell       = document.createElement("td");
                var cellText   = document.createTextNode(vitemno);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vname);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(valias);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vbrand);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                cell       = document.createElement("td");              
                cellText   = document.createTextNode(vdescription);
                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                row.appendChild(cell);

                itemForSaleTableBody.appendChild(row);
}
itemForSaleTable.appendChild(itemForSaleTableBody);
itemForSaleTable.setAttribute("border", "2");       
}
```

//code for creating table skeleton

```
 <table class="CSSTableGenerator" id="custorder1" >
               <thead>
                    <tr id="head1">
                        <th>
                            Item No
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Alias
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Brand
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Description
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
```

//I want to pick the individual cells data so that i can use it to fetch data. How to pick any cell data in selected row, I don't know how to do it! Help me Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind click handler on `tr` then use [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) to move the selected row to another table.

```
$('#custorder1').on('click', 'tr', function(){
    $(this).appendTo('#anotherTableId')
});
```

```js
$('#custorder1').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  $(this).appendTo('#anotherTableId')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="CSSTableGenerator" id="custorder1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Item No
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

Another table

<table class="CSSTableGenerator" id="anotherTableId">

</table>
```

Comment: this works for fetching complete row, but i want cell data , i have updated the question.